# Rails Tutorial Chapter 9 Deploy to Heroku

Tags: railstutorial.org

first time asking on stackoverflow.

I completed chapter 9 of Rails Tutorial.

All the tests go through, the sample_app works fine on the server (I'm using cloud 9 btw). Everything is working...

until I try it after deploying it to Heroku.

So I deployed to Heroku following Hartl's instructions.

I did the $ heroku run rake db:migrate too.

Now, when I try to log in at the Heroku deployed app,

I get the error message :

> "invalid email/password combination".

I'm 100% sure I have the right email/password, and the same email/password combination works fine on the rails server.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? I'm not sure where to even start look for bugs.. (if there are bugs)

Comment: Did you run `$ heroku run rake db:seed` so that you have user accounts in your Heroku app's database?

Comment: that solved the problem! thank you!

Comment: Great! I'll put that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `$ heroku run rake db:seed` so that you populate the database on your Heroku app with user account information.

Comment: @namesake22 If this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the "✔" mark underneath the answer score.